# Have to apply tabbar for single view application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

Iam using xcode4.2 i added 3 items for tabbar in singe view application .

The problem is i cant visualize the output instead of a black screen is shown on ios simulator

Can anyone help me please

my code is

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize appNavigation = _appNavigation;  

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [_appNavigation release];    
    [super dealloc];
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

            UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray *tabsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            `enter code here`ViewController *homeScreen = [[ViewController alloc] init];
            homeScreen.navigationItem.title = @"App Title";
            _appNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeScreen];
            _appNavigation.tabBarItem.title = @"Home";
            [_appNavigation.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_Button.png"]];
            [tabsArray addObject:_appNavigation];
            [_appNavigation release];

            BookmarksViewController *bookMark = [[BookmarksViewController alloc] init];
            bookMark.navigationItem.title = @"Bookmarks";
            _appNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bookMark];
            [_appNavigation.tabBarItem initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks tag:2];
            _appNavigation.tabBarItem.title = @"Bookmarks";
            [tabsArray addObject:_appNavigation];
            [_appNavigation release];

            AppSettingsController *settings = [[AppSettingsController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            settings.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";
            _appNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings];
            _appNavigation.tabBarItem.title = @"Settings";
            [_appNavigation.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Settings_Button.png"]];
            [tabsArray addObject:_appNavigation];
            [_appNavigation release];

            SearchViewController *searchView = [[SearchViewController alloc] init];
            searchView.navigationItem.title = @"Ranga";
            _appNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchView];
            _appNavigation.tabBarItem.title = @"Search";
            [_appNavigation.tabBarItem initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemSearch tag:4];
            [tabsArray addObject:_appNavigation];
            [_appNavigation release];


            tabController.viewControllers = tabsArray;


LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

           [self.window addSubview:tabController.view];

[tabController presentModalViewController:loginView animated:NO];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


@end
```

Comment: i have taken single view application with out story board and i got xib file there.i added 3 view controllers separately i got .h .m and .xib files .

Answer (score 1):

Just update your application code this way.

**1. change in code**

open **AppDelegate.h** file it should be like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FirstViewController,SecondViewController;


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

//these two view controllers (screens) for adding to tabs.
@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstViewController *firstViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondViewController;

//this will be the tab bar-controller
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *baseTabBarController;

@end
```

now your **AppDelegate.m** file code should be like

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"    
#import "FirstViewController .h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize firstViewController;
@synthesize secondViewController;
@synthesize baseTabBarController;



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 

    // create tab bar
    baseTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    baseTabBarController.delegate=self;

    // initialize first screen
    firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController " bundle:nil]; 
    UINavigationController *homeView = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController]; 
    firstViewController.title = @"Home ";

    // initialize second screen
    secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondViewController.title = @"My Favourite";
    UINavigationController *favouriteView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];  

    //add both views in array
    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeView,favouriteView, nil];
    //add array to tab bar  
    baseTabBarController.viewControllers = controllers; 
    //add tab bar to window
    self.window.rootViewController = baseTabBarController;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    

    return YES;
}
```

**2. in UI change**

now go to xib file for both view controller what we want to add TAB,
just change this way in Interface builder

> Bottom Bar = Tab Bar

[image]

that's it!! you will get two tab at the bottom of your application.
[image]

Feel free to ask me if you have any question.

Comment: Thank u I got it.I have a small doubt.Eventhough bottonbar is not setted as tabbar then also I can view tabbar added.Then whats the use of it?

Comment: @user1986984 great to here that :), if my answer helped you, PL accept as answer (make a green tick mark on left side), well it works without adding tabbar in IB, but it will disturb the your UI items, because it adds TabBar programmatically at run time, so we design our layout with adding TabBar so it will be same in Run-time as we Design whole U